# php execution time will increase after 1st ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

In our ajax call, we try to select some value from database those values needs to be stored into one temporary table that we create when the script is running then we try to do few operation and result would come through json format to Ajax calling script. For 1st ajax call takes 15 seconds. then for 2nd it takes 19 seconds.i don't know why it takes more 4 seconds than 1st Ajax call.I thought it was buffer size problem then i have cleaned my system using **CCleaner** software after it takes only 14 seconds. To do the same we use **ob_flush();** **flush();** functions and **cache:false** in ajax call also. it is doing the same. but still it takes 19 seconds. Could you please suggest me what was the error or what needs to be done? I mean which php function needs to be called to do the same?

this ajax call

```
                 var form = $('#chart_form');
             var formdata = false;
             if(window.FormData){
                 formdata = new FormData(form[0]);
             }
             var formAction = form.attr('action');



            $.ajax({
           url: 'process.php',
           type: 'POST',
               cache       : false,
               data        : formdata ? formdata : form.serialize(),
               contentType : false,
               processData : false,
                dataType: "json",
                timeout : 10000000,
                beforeSend: function () { 
    $('#wait').html('<span style="position: fixed;left: 50%;top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); color:#3C8DBC "><img src="images/waiting.gif" alt="loading" width="200" height="200" style="padding-left:85px"><br /><br /><span style=" font-weight: 700; font-size: 18px">Please wait,Chart is being Generated</span></span>');
    $('#wait').css({display: "block" });

    $('#message').css({display: "block" });

            },

           success: function(data) 
              {
//do operation
}
         complete: function(r) {
                       //alert(r.responseText);

        $('#message').css({display: "none" });
        $("#wait").css({display: "none" });
    $(window).scrollTop(200); 

        }
});
```

In ajax page,table has 3 million data.we are selecting 11,000 data.

```
<?php 
ob_flush();
        flush();
$client=trim($_POST['client']);
 $ip=trim($_POST['IP']);
$port=trim($_POST['port']);
$var=trim($_POST['variable']);
$start=trim($_POST['start']);
$end=trim($_POST['end']);
$new_start = date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($start));
$new_end = date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($end));
$t=time();

$character='2346789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$total_no_char=strlen($character)-1;
$final_char=mt_rand(0,$total_no_char);
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
{
    $string .= $character[mt_rand(0,$total_no_char)];
}

$table_name=$t.'_'.$string.'_list';
$create_table="
CREATE TABLE $table_name (status varchar(100),moddate datetime,  
INDEX mod_index (moddate)) SELECT `status`,`moddate`
   FROM `globstats_graph`
   WHERE Cname='$client' AND IP='$ip'
   AND Port='$port' AND Variable='$var' AND status REGEXP '^[0-9]+$|^ON$'
   AND moddate between '$new_start' and '$new_end'";
mysql_query($create_table);
?>
```

After that we are doing some operation in temporary table.and pass response in json format.In json format,I am passing two array.each array has 90 values

Comment: set some of youe code

Comment: Not enough information.

Comment: Could you please provide more details ?

Comment: I have added more details in question.Please check it.@ashkufaraz, @DeDee,@hutchbat

Comment: do you flush the browsers cookie also by ccleaner

Comment: yes I have flushed browser cookie also @siddhesh

Comment: then for the second call it might sending the cookie also and so the time will be increase i m not sure

Comment: please do NOT use the (deprecated) `mysql` functions anymore, but use something like PDO in stead. Your current code is wide open to mysql injection btw...

Comment: @Pevara can i use MYSQLi for prevent mysql injection

Comment: @siddhesh I ain't using any cookies in my code. if ajax call generates cookies,please let me how to delete ajax cookies in Ajax call.

Comment: with firebug or any other inspector inspect ajax request and check request header contents as well as response

Comment: @siddhesh Response header shows like this Connection Keep-Alive
Content-Length 2953
Content-Type application/json
Date Mon, 23 Mar 2015 16:04:08 GMT
Keep-Alive timeout=5, max=100
Server Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) PHP/5.3.13
X-Powered-By PHP/5.3.13.Request Header shows like this

Comment: @siddhesh response show like this{"0":[[1420072320000,642686.38845086],[1420102080000,498380.03832434],[1420131840000,506838.56541736],]} it has 90 values.i show example values.what will i do?

Comment: is the both response content-length is same

Comment: is the both request sending the same data, is the request header shows  the cookies?

Comment: all that you have to analyse i cannot say by just seeing your comments if you are doing it online then give me link i will try to analyse

Comment: @siddhesh we have developed in local host only.After implement that thing then only we will put on server.content length of response header both are same(1st call Content-Length is 2910 & 2nd call is  2910). But content length of request header are different.(1st call is 684 and 2nd call is 697).In cookies section shows empty value.what will i do?Otherwise can i show project using teamviewer?

Comment: thats why you get more time

Comment: @siddhesh Please let me know how can i rectify that thing?

Comment: I really like to help you but I've not time in my busy schedule but if you can find the reason behind the scene I will definately say that you can also solve the problem. just analyze the request which thing is extra added into 2nd call and try to remove it.  **Best of luck**

Comment: @siddhesh thanks for your help till now.Please give me suggestion for last thing.Today I have checked response header content-length and  request header content length are increased.but i have checked both content from post section and response section.In both ajax call have same content.but content length is different.I don't know how to rectify it.Please give me some idea how to solve it.then i will follow instructions

Comment: now you have cheked the data that is being  posted, check also the request header,cookies section or check the post data is somewhere have the blank spaces which is not seen by eyes if its end of line.